# JavaFX attach event listener to circles with color black

Tags: java, groovy, javafx, java-8, javafx-8

I'm a total novice when it comes to Java but I'm trying to build a checkers game. I have constructed a board but I'm stumped exactly how and where best to add some sort of event listener for mouse hovering and clicking.

I've used a combination of Groovy and JavaFX, Groovy because I liked the syntax and JavaFX because it seemed the better alternative to Swing.

```
class Window extends Application {

    private int boardSize = 8
    private int squareSize = 60

    void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Draughts")
        GridPane checkerBoard = new GridPane()
        checkerBoard.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10))

        configureBoardSpecs(checkerBoard)

        layoutBoard(checkerBoard)

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(checkerBoard);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 500))


        primaryStage.show()
    }

    private void layoutBoard(def checkerBoard) {
        def fill = Color.WHITE

        for (row in 0..boardSize-1) {
            for (col in 0..boardSize-1) {
                if ((row+col)%2) {
                    fill = Color.SADDLEBROWN
                } else {
                    fill = Color.PERU
                }
                checkerBoard.add(new Rectangle(squareSize, squareSize, fill), col, row)

                if (row % 2 != col % 2) {
                    if (row < 3) {
                        checkerBoard.add(new Circle(squareSize/2-4, Color.WHITE), col, row)
                    } else if (row > 4) {
                        checkerBoard.add(new Circle(squareSize/2-4, Color.BLACK), col, row)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void configureBoardSpecs(def board) {
        for (i in 0..boardSize-1) {
            RowConstraints rowConstraints = new RowConstraints()
            rowConstraints.setMinHeight(squareSize)
            rowConstraints.setPrefHeight(squareSize)
            rowConstraints.setMaxHeight(squareSize)
            rowConstraints.setValignment(VPos.CENTER)
            board.getRowConstraints().add(rowConstraints)

            ColumnConstraints colConstraints = new ColumnConstraints()
            colConstraints.setMinWidth(squareSize)
            colConstraints.setMaxWidth(squareSize)
            colConstraints.setPrefWidth(squareSize)
            colConstraints.setHalignment(HPos.CENTER)
            board.getColumnConstraints().add(colConstraints)
        }
    }
```

I'm a lot more practised doing this sort of thing with jQuery where I would use a selector to grab any sort of circle with the color black and have it so when the mouse cursor hovered over, it would add a border to the circle. Then on click, the color of the entire circle or encompassing rectangle would change color.

Any helpful suggestions as to the best way to go about this.

Many thanks,

Comment: Mystery down-voter please comment if there's something you don't like about my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a reference to the circles when you create them, so you can add the listeners. For example (note: I use Java, not Groovy, so the syntax may not match, however this will give you the idea):

```
Circle circle = new Circle(squareSize/2-4, Color.WHITE) ;
circle.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
    // handler code...
});
checkerBoard.add(circle, col, row) ;
```

Comment: Cheers, what you suggested was actually quite simple. I managed to do it the way I was thinking but it seemed far less eloquent. As an aside, have you an idea how to mass assign mouse events within one handler?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that other question.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it the way I was proposing:

```
    children = checkerBoard.getChildren()
        for (child in children) {
            if (child instanceof Circle) {
                child.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                        child.setStroke(Color.ORANGE);
                    }
                })
            }
        }
```

However @James_D answer seemed better